Take another run at tagging on Bitcoin.SE?
There is still a bunch of tags left that need work from the Weeding out bad tags initiative 2014. I’d be willing to invest some time to go through the tags once more and pre-select some to work on. Also, we have whole swamps of duplicates many of which have no useful answers or some of which could be merged to collect good answers in one place.
I can’t do it by myself though, so I’m wondering how we could organize the work to collaborate without wasting time by looking at everything several times, e.g. if we take a crack at big tags such as alternatives.
Any thoughts?
